# Save the input from the user make even after reload/refresh

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to to add a function that every time the user refresh, reload or even close the page, the user to able to see the data (added books) whatever the user had entered previously or choose in the .

Also when the user make an update and refresh they show be able to see the change.

### javascript file

```
console.log('This is ES6 version of project 2');

class Book {

    constructor(name, author, type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.author = author;
        this.type = type;
    }
}

class Display {
    add(book) {
        console.log('Adding to UI');
        let tableBody = document.getElementById('tableBody')
        let uiString = `<tr>
                            <td>${book.name}</td>
                            <td>${book.author}</td>
                            <td>${book.type}</td>
                        </tr>`;
        tableBody.innerHTML += uiString;

    }

    clear() {
        let libraryForm = document.getElementById('libraryForm');
        libraryForm.reset();
    }

    validate(book) {
        if (book.name.length < 2 || book.author.length < 2) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    show (type, displayMessage) {
        let message = document.getElementById('message');
        let boldText;
        if (type === 'success'){
            boldText = 'Success';
        }
        else{
            boldText = 'Error!';
        }
        message.innerHTML = `<div class="alert alert-${type} alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                                <strong>${boldText}:</strong> ${displayMessage}
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>`
    
        setTimeout(function () {
            message.innerHTML = '';
        }, 5000);
    
    }
}

// Add submit event listener to libraryForm
let libraryForm = document.getElementById('libraryForm');
libraryForm.addEventListener('submit', libraryFormSubmit);

function libraryFormSubmit(e) {
    console.log('You have submitted library form')
    let name = document.getElementById('bookName').value;
    let author = document.getElementById('author').value;
    let type;
    let fiction = document.getElementById('fiction');
    let programming = document.getElementById('programming');
    let cooking = document.getElementById('cooking');
    if (fiction.checked) {
        type = fiction.value;
    }
    else if (programming.checked) {
        type = programming.value;
    }
    else if (cooking.checked) {
        type = cooking.value;
    }

    let book = new Book(name, author, type);
    console.log(book);

    let display = new Display();
    if (display.validate(book)) {

        display.add(book);
        display.clear();
        display.show('success', 'Your book has been successfully added')
    }
    else {
        // show error to the user
        display.show('danger', 'Sorry you cannot add this book.')
    }

    e.preventDefault();
}
```

HTML File

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <title>Welcome to Juggu library</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark ">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/index.html">Juggu library</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/index.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/about.html">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
                          aria-expanded="false">
                          Websites
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="//allyouneed-notesapp.netlify.app/index.html">AllYouNeed Notes App</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="//textutilssystem.herokuapp.com">Text Utils</a>
                          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="//github.com/Mohammedvaraliya">github Profile</a>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="d-flex" role="search">
                    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div id="message">

        <!-- <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
            <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> You should check in on some of those fields below.
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div> -->
          
    </div>

    <div class="container my-3" id="notes">
        <form id="libraryForm">
            <h1>Juggu library</h1>
            <hr>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="bookName" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bookName" placeholder="Book Name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="Author" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Author</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="author" placeholder="Author">
                </div>
            </div>
            <fieldset class="form-group row">
                <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 float-sm-left pt-0">Type</legend>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="type" id="fiction" value="fiction" checked>
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="fiction">
                            Fiction
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="type" id="programming" value="programming">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="Programming">
                            Computer Programming
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="type" id="cooking" value="cooking">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="cooking">
                            Cooking
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="addBtn">Add Book</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

        <div id="table">

            <h1>Your Books</h1>
            <table class="table table-dark table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Author</th>
                        <th scope="col">Type</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tableBody"> </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
    <!-- <script src="js/index.js"></script> -->
    <script src="js/indexes6.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-VHvPCCyXqtD5DqJeNxl2dtTyhF78xXNXdkwX1CZeRusQfRKp+tA7hAShOK/B/fQ2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
</body>

</html>
```

---

Comment: Using cookies or localStorage should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is you need to use something permanent to store the data on, such as a database in the cloud, or simply for your simple app, you can use the browser built-in APIs for the [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Which can be added on your `.add()` method, whenever a book is added, save it to the local storage.

And whenever the app launches, run an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to fill the table with the data stored in the local storage

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


  <title>Welcome to Juggu library</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark ">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/index.html">Juggu library</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/index.html">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/about.html">About Us</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                          Websites
                        </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="//allyouneed-notesapp.netlify.app/index.html">AllYouNeed Notes App</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="//textutilssystem.herokuapp.com">Text Utils</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="//github.com/Mohammedvaraliya">github Profile</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="d-flex" role="search">
          <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div id="message">

    <!-- <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
            <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> You should check in on some of those fields below.
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div> -->

  </div>

  <div class="container my-3" id="notes">
    <form id="libraryForm">
      <h1>Juggu library</h1>
      <hr>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="bookName" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bookName" placeholder="Book Name">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="Author" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Author</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="author" placeholder="Author">
        </div>
      </div>
      <fieldset class="form-group row">
        <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 float-sm-left pt-0">Type</legend>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="type" id="fiction" value="fiction" checked>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="fiction">
                            Fiction
                        </label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="type" id="programming" value="programming">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="Programming">
                            Computer Programming
                        </label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="type" id="cooking" value="cooking">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="cooking">
                            Cooking
                        </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="addBtn">Add Book</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>

    <div id="table">

      <h1>Your Books</h1>
      <table class="table table-dark table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Author</th>
            <th scope="col">Type</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tableBody"> </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

  <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
  <!-- <script src="js/index.js"></script> -->
  <script src="js/indexes6.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
  <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-VHvPCCyXqtD5DqJeNxl2dtTyhF78xXNXdkwX1CZeRusQfRKp+tA7hAShOK/B/fQ2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
</body>

</html>
```

```js
console.log("This is ES6 version of project 2");

const uid = function () {
  return Date.now().toString(36) + Math.random().toString(36).slice(2);
};

class Book {
  constructor(name, author, type) {
    this.id = uid();
    this.name = name;
    this.author = author;
    this.type = type;
  }
}

class Display {
  add(book) {
    console.log("Adding to UI");
    let tableBody = document.getElementById("tableBody");
    let uiString = `<tr>
                            <td>${book.name}</td>
                            <td>${book.author}</td>
                            <td>${book.type}</td>
                        </tr>`;
    tableBody.innerHTML += uiString;

    // save the data to the browser's local storage -----
    const books = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("books"));
    console.log(books);
    if (!books.some((oldBook) => oldBook.id === book.id)) books.push(book);
    localStorage.setItem("books", JSON.stringify(books));
  }

  clear() {
    let libraryForm = document.getElementById("libraryForm");
    libraryForm.reset();
  }

  validate(book) {
    if (book.name.length < 2 || book.author.length < 2) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }

  show(type, displayMessage) {
    let message = document.getElementById("message");
    let boldText;
    if (type === "success") {
      boldText = "Success";
    } else {
      boldText = "Error!";
    }
    message.innerHTML = `<div class="alert alert-${type} alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                                <strong>${boldText}:</strong> ${displayMessage}
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>`;

    setTimeout(function () {
      message.innerHTML = "";
    }, 5000);
  }
}

// Add submit event listener to libraryForm
let libraryForm = document.getElementById("libraryForm");
libraryForm.addEventListener("submit", libraryFormSubmit);

function libraryFormSubmit(e) {
  console.log("You have submitted library form");
  let name = document.getElementById("bookName").value;
  let author = document.getElementById("author").value;
  let type;
  let fiction = document.getElementById("fiction");
  let programming = document.getElementById("programming");
  let cooking = document.getElementById("cooking");
  if (fiction.checked) {
    type = fiction.value;
  } else if (programming.checked) {
    type = programming.value;
  } else if (cooking.checked) {
    type = cooking.value;
  }

  let book = new Book(name, author, type);
  console.log(book);

  let display = new Display();
  if (display.validate(book)) {
    display.add(book);
    display.clear();
    display.show("success", "Your book has been successfully added");
  } else {
    // show error to the user
    display.show("danger", "Sorry you cannot add this book.");
  }

  e.preventDefault();
}

(() => {
  const display = new Display();
  let books = localStorage.getItem("books");
  if (books) {
    books = JSON.parse(books);
    books.forEach((book) => display.add(book));
  } else localStorage.setItem("books", JSON.stringify([]));
})();
```

Comment: HandsOff to you, Its really really very very helpful 

But whenever i reload the page ,so whatever the books which has already added is added multiple,

Comment: whenever i reload the page so it will not adding multiple for only first time reload but when i reload multiple times so it is adding the all books mutiple times 
so as much i understand i have to give the condition to adding method 
that 
if (book.name) || (book.author) ==;
 return; 
else{
 display.add(book); 


am i right.

Comment: hey can u please solve this , i tried but am not getting that point , so please

Comment: @MohammedVaraliya, Aha, yes I forgot that. you should add a unique id to each book, so I modified the Book constructor to generate a unique id for every book using the function `uid`, the IIFE is the same, but the difference is now in the `display.prototype.add`method, now it checks before saving to the local storage if the book has already got an ID stored in there. Hope this solves the problem